# Javascript heatmap ReferenceError h337.create

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, typeerror, heatmap

I am modifying an existing project from github which uses heatmap.js to generate a heatmap from a match in the game "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive", the original developer did not seem to finish this part of the code or it has bugs in it. The Firebug console says this as the only error:

```
ReferenceError: h337 is not defined
var heatmap = h337.create(
```

This is the line that it seems to blame: https://github.com/deStrO/eBot-CSGO-Web/blob/master/apps/backend/modules/matchs/templates/_stats_heatmap.php#L26

I think there is a typo/error somewhere here, after spending hours trying to locate it I am unable to do so.

I tried generating a heatmap using both Chrome (v46.0.2490.80), Firefox (v41.0.2) however nothing happens and the only error logged is the TypeError one which is all I have to go after.

Any tips/hints as to what can be causing this? I have been googling/searching stackoverflow for similar issues without success, I think there is something silly I am overlooking..

Comment: Have you tried to replace `var heatmap = h337.create(...` for `var heatmap = new HeatmapOverlay(`? It was the solution for me

Comment: is the library even loaded?

Comment: @Sapikelio That also yields the same thing.

Comment: @Alex I think you might be onto something..

Comment: @dusz are you using Windows Xp?

Comment: @Sapikelio Negative, Fedora 23 and Windows 10. Regarding the library lodaded: I see the `<script>` tag and clicking it yields the source of heatmap.js.

Comment: wrap all yout script inside `$( document ).ready(function() {
});`. Maybe you are calling h337 before script is loaded

Comment: @Sapikelio I tried replacing `window.onload = function() {` with `$(document).ready(function() {` Still the same error in console.

Comment: you have to console.log() tear down , locate the error by checking if it is logged before the error, are you really sure it is not sth in your code?

Comment: the last line in heatmap.js is `w.h337 = w.heatmapFactory = heatmapFactory;`

Comment: @johnSmith What about this line?

Comment: check the window object if there is h337 property and maybe change code to `heatmap = w.h337.create`

Comment: @johnSmith it seems like it is not there, it now says w not defined. Perhaps its easier for you to see for yourself? http://46.166.176.229/eBot-CSGO/matchs/view/14#heatmap if you can see that let me know.

Answer (score 3):

change this line

```
var heatmap = h337.create(
```

to

```
var heatmap = window.h337.create(
```

Update:

okay you are lucky i found the error, you have to pass the "container" property to the heatmap options:

```
    heatmap = window.h337.create(
    {
        "container": document.getElementById("heatmapArea"),
        "element": document.getElementById("heatmapArea"),
        "radius" : 11,
        "opacity": 40,
        "visible": true,
        "gradient" : { 0.45: "rgb(0,0,255)", 0.55: "rgb(0,255,255)", 0.65: "rgb(0,255,0)", 0.95: "yellow", 1: "rgb(255,0,0)"}
    })
```

for me this works :)

Comment: Seems not to work either strange, try refreshing and check aswell. If you view page source you can see the library looks to be loaded. http://46.166.176.229/eBot-CSGO/matchs/view/14#heatmap

Comment: if you enter `window.h337` into the console it is set and working

Comment: Hey @johnsmith I will check when I am home, I was in a meeting. I updated the code which I think reflects what you wrote now, but initial testing does not work. I may have missed something as I just tested before going home now. Do you use the `window.onload = function(){` method or the `$(document).ready(function(){` method?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR

Disable uBlock Origin (or possibly some other Firefox Add-on) on the pages that exhibit this error.

Answer:
This happened to me in Firefox but not in Chrome. In Chrome, everything worked as expected, so I started to suspect my Firefox Add-ons. I disabled everything and discovered that the maps now worked in Firefox. After carefully re-enabling all Add-ons, I discovered that the uBlock Origin add-on was interfering with the javascript. Simply disabling uBlock Origin on the page you are loading in Firefox is sufficient to permit the script to function properly.

Answer (score -1):

I had some code very similar to this that broke because I was using window.onload to load the maps but also had a different onload function in my body tag that was empty.  At some point, it looks like the browser switched from ignoring the empty body tag to causing it to disable/overwrite the window.onload.  This was hard to track down as there were no errors.